# Sharepoint ribbon button click not executing on I.E

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I have a custom ribbon button that i am deploying to a custom SharePoint Edit form. I have deployed the same code/logic to other forms with no problem. The ribbon button is showing up at the correct place inside the custom Edit form, however, it throws a javascript null exception when I click it. Even a simple alert won't work. This only happens on Internet Explorer (all versions). It works on chrome. Here is the ribbon elements.xml:

```
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Displays" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm"
            RegistrationId="10000"
            RegistrationType="List" Title="Add Ribbon Customization">
  <CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.Controls._children" >
      <Button Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.AttachFiles" Command="Command_AttachFiles"
       Image16by16="_LAYOUTS/$Resources:core,Language;/IMAGES/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-128" Image16by16Left="-144"
       Image32by32="_LAYOUTS/$Resources:core,Language;/IMAGES/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-352" Image32by32Left="-128"
       LabelText="Attach File" TemplateAlias="o1" Sequence="2"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Command_AttachFiles" CommandAction="javascript:alert('Test Ribbon');" />

 </CommandUIHandlers>
 </CommandUIExtension>
 </CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is quite old, let me suggest a solution:

When debugging Ribbon buttons/behavior in IE, you should use InPrivate mode window which you should close after each deployment of the solution. It can happen that IE caches old version of the solution which can cause headache and long hours